# I've got a loooong boot time again! This time it's crazily long! +10 min

Tags: 18.04, systemd, snap, boot-time

This has become my nightmare with Ubuntu... since I'm using it (version 14.x). Everything works slick a couple of weeks after a fresh installation but I have no idea what happens in between so that suddenly I have to wait a couple of minutes for rebooting my relatively performant Laptop (a high-end ThinkPad). On the net I couldn't find a consistent solution… there are various consumptions and suggestions on changing `fstab` etc. but these are not the issue… Does anybody know how I could solve this?

[image]

Comment: More of a workaround than an actual solution, but if you don't use snaps, you can just remove the snapd package. Otherwise, best wait for someone else who knows more than I do.